# Unity3d : can't add script component in the gameobject because of C# Native Integration

Tags: unity-game-engine

Everytime I try to add new script to any prefab Im getting this message

"Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found. Make sure there are no compile errors"

And yes the file name matches.

I'm using the latest version currently 2018.3.5f1

I was using recently "Unity C# 5.0 and 6.0 Integration" from [here](https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src)
because I was having this kind of error in the console

"error CS1644: cannot be used, because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification."

After that not knowing how to uninstall this I removed the folder and reimported the asset

Now I'm having this error which causing me the script component add, supposedly

> UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.ScriptCompilerBase.BeginCompiling () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/Compilers/ScriptCompilerBase.cs:60)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.QueuePendingAssemblies () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/CompilationTask.cs:228)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.CompilationTask.Poll () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/CompilationTask.cs:135)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileScriptAssemblies (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssembly[] scriptAssemblies, UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory, EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, CompilationTaskOptions compilationTaskOptions, CompileScriptAssembliesOptions compileScriptAssembliesOptions) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:1133)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileCustomScriptAssemblies (UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.ScriptAssemblySettings scriptAssemblySettings, System.String tempBuildDirectory, EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, BuildTarget platform) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:1045)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilation.CompileCustomScriptAssemblies (EditorScriptCompilationOptions options, BuildTargetGroup platformGroup, BuildTarget platform) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilation.cs:1039)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface+c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:277)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface.EmitExceptionAsError[Boolean] (System.Func`1 func, Boolean returnValue) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Scripting/ScriptCompilation/EditorCompilationInterface.cs:97)
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.ScriptCompilation.EditorCompilationInterface:CompileCustomScriptAssemblies(EditorScriptCompilationOptions, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget)

Any ideas ?

Comment: `error CS1644: cannot be used, because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification` -> make sure you are using `.Net4.X` not `.Net3.5` in `PlayerSettings`->`Others`->`Scripting Backend`. Make also sure the component class has exactly the same name as the script file

Comment: I did doesn't resolve the last error mentioned

Comment: Could you post your script somewhere?

Comment: I would have to know first which one it is causing the issue

Comment: Oh I see .. I read for some people the only solution was to reinstall Unity .. might be a bug?

Comment: reinstalling unity did not resolve anything my project is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to export my asset package

Reinstall unity

Create new project folder

And Import the asset, the error are gone turn out my folder was the issue